# Parsing malformed JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, json, parsing

Thanks for looking!

## BACKGROUND

I am writing some front-end code that consumes a JSON service which is returning malformed JSON.  Specifically, the keys are not surrounded with quotes:

```
{foo: "bar"}
```

I have NO CONTROL over the service, so I am correcting this like so:

```
var scrubbedJson = dirtyJson.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');
```

This gives me well formed JSON:

{"foo": "bar"}

## Problem

However, when I call `JSON.parse(scrubbedJson)`, I still get an error.  I suspect it may be because the entire JSON string is surrounded in double quotes but I am not sure.

## UPDATE

This has been solved--the above code works fine.  I had a rogue single quote in the body of the JSON that was returned.  I got that out of there and everything now parses.  Thanks.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what's actually returned by the service?  Yes, if the entire string is surrounded by double quotes it's still not valid JSON.

Comment: Also, can you fix the service?

Comment: You can assume that the following would be returned: `"{"foo":"bar"}"`.  I am terrible with `regex`. Do you know how this would be cured?

Comment: Fixing the service is unfortunately not an option.  I have no control over it.

Comment: That regular expression will just quote *any* sequence of letters and digits before a colon, including those already appearing within quotes. You can't really solve this problem with a regular expression. You'll have to write your own custom JSON-like parser, or else feed the stuff directly to the JavaScript interpreter (if you're feeling lucky).

Comment: If your problem is the existence of " at the start and end. Then just use a substring call to chop it off?

Comment: You're almost there! You're on the right track preprocessing the JSON, just add another rule to remove the quotes at the beginning and end of the malformed JSON string. Also, if I were you, I would contact the service and send them a link to this question in order to help others, as well as encourage the service to fix the json output!

Comment: FYI your REGEX has issues if there are any colons `:` in the malformed JSON, for example if one of the values is `https://www.somesite.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this may help to repair the json ..

```
$str='{foo:"bar"}';
echo preg_replace('/({)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:)/','$1"$2"${3}',$str);
```

Output:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

EDIT:

```
var str='{foo:"bar"}';
str.replace(/({)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:)/,'$1"$2"$3')
```

Comment: not sure why I put it in php ??  var str='{foo:"bar"}';str.replace(/({)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(:)/,'$1"$2"$3')

Comment: Fails on: str = '{foo: "bar", foo2: "{foo:bar}"}'

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using a regexp altogether and still output a JavaScript object from a malformed JSON string (keys without quotes, single quotes, etc), using this simple trick:

```
var jsonify = (function(div){
  return function(json){
    div.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.__json__ = ' + json);
    div.click();
    return div.__json__;
  }
})(document.createElement('div'));

// Let's say you had a string like '{ one: 1 }' (malformed, a key without quotes)
// jsonify('{ one: 1 }') will output a good ol' JS object ;)
```

**Here's a demo:** http://codepen.io/csuwldcat/pen/dfzsu (open your console)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project that takes care of all kinds of invalid cases in JSON https://github.com/freethenation/durable-json-lint

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem using a regEx in Javascript.  I have an app written for Node.js to parse incoming JSON, but wanted  a "relaxed" version of the parser (see following comments), since it is inconvenient to put quotes around every key (name).  Here is my solution:

```
var objKeysRegex = /({|,)(?:\s*)(?:')?([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)(?:')?(?:\s*):/g;// look for object names
var newQuotedKeysString = originalString.replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":");// all object names should be double quoted
var newObject = JSON.parse(newQuotedKeysString);
```

Here's a breakdown of the regEx:

- `({|,)` looks for the beginning of the object, a `{` for flat objects or `,` for embedded objects.
- `(?:\s*)` finds but does not remember white space
- `(?:')?` finds but does not remember a single quote (to be replaced by a double quote later).  There will be either zero or one of these.
- `([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)` is the name (or key). Starts with any letter, underscore, $, or dot, followed by zero or more alpha-numeric characters or underscores or dashes or dots or $.
- the last character `:` is what delimits the name of the object from the value.

Now we can use `replace()` with some dressing to get our newly quoted keys:

```
originalString.replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":")
```

where the `$1` is either `{` or `,` depending on whether the object was embedded in another object.  `\"` adds a double quote.  `$2` is the name. `\"` another double quote. and finally `:` finishes it off.
Test it out with

```
{keyOne: "value1", $keyTwo: "value 2", key-3:{key4:18.34}}
```

output:

```
{"keyOne": "value1","$keyTwo": "value 2","key-3":{"key4":18.34}}
```

Some comments:

- I have not tested this method for speed, but from what I gather by reading some of these entries is that using a regex is faster than `eval()`
- For my application, I'm limiting the characters that names are allowed to have with `([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)` for my 'relaxed' version JSON parser.  If you wanted to allow more characters in names (you can do that and still be valid), you could instead use `([^'":]+)` to mean anything other than double or single quotes or a colon.  You can have all sorts of stuff in here with this expression, so be careful.
- One shortcoming is that this method actually changes the original incoming data (but I think that's what you wanted?).  You could program around that to mitigate this issue - depends on your needs and resources available.

Hope this helps.
-John L.

Answer (score -1):

How about?

```
function fixJson(json) {
    var tempString, tempJson, output;

    tempString = JSON.stringify(json);
    tempJson = JSON.parse(tempString);
    output = JSON.stringify(tempJson);

    return output;
}
```