# missing quotation marks on keys in JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json, node.js

I have a string containing malformed JSON which is being provided to me where the keys are missing the quotation marks.  The structure of the JSON is out of my control, so I need to work with what I have.
I have found the solution that the OP posts in [Parsing malformed JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18280279/1074891) works, however one of the values contains a URL that the RegEx matches and transforms it into another key like value, resulting in really broken JSON. Any ideas?

I have also looked at [jsonrepair](https://github.com/vmx/jsonrepair), but not having much success there.

Comment: do values have always double quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it.  All you needed to do was identify when a colon was followed by a forward-slash (like in http://) instead of in isolation.  Note that this will fail in the event that one of your JSON values has a colon in it, so it may need more improvement for your use case.

```
.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:([^\/])/g, '"$2":$4');
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! Thanks dan.

Comment: Just re-reading my answer, I realised that I assumed the value immediately followed the colon (`key:"value"` vs. `key: "value"`) when I added the quote to the end of the second param.  I'm updating the answer with the correct code in case there's a space there, so you don't get double-quotes.

Answer (score 9):

If the only thing wrong with the JSON is property names without quotes, then it is still a valid JavaScript object literal even though it isn't valid JSON.

So, *if you trust the source*, you can wrap the text in parentheses and `eval` it.

This will be simpler and more reliable than any regular expression.

Example:

```
var badJSON = '{ a: "b" }';
var obj = eval( '(' + badJSON + ')' );
console.log( obj );    // Logs: Object {a: "b"}
console.log( obj.a );  // Logs: b
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Michael, unfortunately I don't trust anyone :)