# How to parse javascript object string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I have a string representation of an object, in a template string, like this

```
const obj = `
{
  namespace: 'ignored',
  state: {}
}
`
```

Now I want to parse that into an object, but `JSON.parse` throws an error.

```
JSON.parse(obj)
//=> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 13(…)
```

thats because `JSON.parse` expect a json string like this

```
const obj = `
{
  "namespace": "ignored",
  "state": {}
}
`
```

Now, I can't manually change my `obj` object, because is an user input, and can be way more complex. So, is there any way to parse it? before using JSON.parse, maybe some regex, or maybe some other method better than JSON.parse?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `eval` is your best shot... depends on where the input is coming from though. `JSON.parse` can't work since it expects JSON, not JavaScript.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. It's just a js object inside a template string... I'd invest in creating a valid JSON object.

Comment: I agree, but how? Thats why I also suggested some valid regex to transform my js object in a valid json to be parsed

Comment: Running user input into `eval` seems like a great idea. Why would some people ever think that's not safe?!

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira Depends on where it came from and what you're doing with it. If it's user input and you render it for every user, it's not safe. If it's simply executed on the user's behalf, then it isn't too bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175802/missing-quotation-marks-on-keys-in-json

Comment: That code snippet works fine for me (Chrome 53), by the way

Comment: Not in my chrome 53, or in node v4.x

Comment: @JonSG thanks a lot. that was what I needed :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do a few things.

- Use a proper parser.
- Use `eval()`.

For most applications, particularly if there is any user-input there that will end up on other user's computers, `eval()`'s a terrible idea. Probably only useful here for a throwaway script or similar.

For parsing, define its input grammar, parse it into a tree structure and then directly create the JavaScript object you need. Since it looks like actual JavaScript code, you could use an existing parser and it will be much easier.

Comment: Is a tool meant to be user for other libraries, not a web input. So by "user" I'm talking about other developers

Comment: What _existing parser_ could I use? if JSNO.parser throws error?

Comment: @YerkoPalma Just a quick look, but I found [esprima](http://esprima.org/).