# How to parse object from string in JS (it was console logged)?

Tags: javascript

I have a log file that contains several objects that i printed with console.log. I made JSON-like strings with regexp, and now I need to parse them somehow. Object string could be something like

```
{ id: 2922,  valid: true,  filled: true,  data:   [ '1-a', '2-c' ] }
```

JSON.parse doesn't work here since keys are not quoted. Any ideas on how could that be parsed?

UPD: tried `eval(str)`, but got the error

```
const str = "{ id: 2922,  valid: true,  filled: true,  data:   [ '1-a', '2- c' ] } ";
const obj = eval(str);
console.log(obj);
```

the error is:

```
undefined:1
{ id: 2922,  valid: true,  filled: true,  data:   [ '1-a', '2-c' ] }
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Clouds\Git\career-pulse-fix-from-logs\b.js:2:18)
```

Comment: When you made JSON-like strings then why not JSON strings?

Comment: One option is to add quotes and then use JSON.parse, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175802/missing-quotation-marks-on-keys-in-json

Comment: @AshishRanjan well.... that's why I call them json-LIKE, not JSON

Comment: My few lines of code make it work perfectly and prevent to use eval() which is not appreciated in many languages and can be really dangerous.

Comment: @DmitrySamoylov    Ashish is not questioning the wording `json-LIKE`, but is asking when you initially created the file, why didn't you use JSON then?.

Comment: @Keith that was just a debug log, I wasn't going to parse. But now I need to do it to recover some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not valid JSON, this is valid JS. So, you could parse it by [js's `eval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) that gets a js expression and returns its result. like:

```js
const str = "{ id: 2922, valid: true, filled: true,  data: ['1-a', '2- c'] }";
const obj = eval('(' + str + ')');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work (please see updated question)

Comment: fixed it with `var obj = eval( '(' + strObj+ ')' );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var json = str.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:([^\/])/g, '"$2":$4');` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175802/missing-quotation-marks-on-keys-in-json)) to add quote to your keys, **BUT** the value of the `data` field is still not wrote in a good JSON syntax.

**EDIT**
This script looks to work !

```
var str = "{ id: 2922,  valid: true,  filled: true,  data:   [ '1-a', '2-c' ] } ";
var json = str.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:([^\/])/g, '"$2":$4');
json = json.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```