# JavaScript - matching keys with regex in malformed JSON

Tags: javascript, json, regex, steam

I'm trying to fix some almost JSON code sent sometimes by Steam instead of correct one. The main problem I have are keys. There is a [stack topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280279/parsing-malformed-json-in-javascript) about fixing similar issues but it's not perfect. Matching keys with `/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g` matches also http links or inline css.

Is it possible to match `/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g` that aren't in strings matchable by `([\'](?:.)*[\'])` (this one matches values) ?

Sample malformed JSON:

```
{
    app_data: 
    { '123': 
        { 
            appid: 123,
            name: 'some game',
            icon: 'http://example.com',
            test: 'some text with link http://steamcommunity.com don't match it please',
            sample: 'blah blah background: red; blah blah' 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like a well-formed javascript :) If you trust the source enought you could simply use `eval`. Which is of course evil but not as much as trying to "fix" something using regexp.

Comment: it's not well-formed javascript, because of the unescaped quote mark in "don't". Can you rely on the key/value pairs that you want to match being on one line? If so, you could match the whole lot  with something like `/([^ {]*?):(.*)/`, then replace with `"$1":$2`

Comment: "because of the unescaped quote mark in "don't"" I believe it was a typo.

Comment: I suspect it's a typo as well. user1100671, can you explain why you think the JSON returned by Steam is invalid?

Comment: I did the 'typo' on purpose. That's why I'm looking for a way to match strings `/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g` that aren't in strings matchable by `/([\'](?:.)*[\'])/g `

Comment: @user1100671 So you are saying that Steam is sending malformed javascript? Because javascript object literals and JSON are different things. And what you have posted is not a JSON its javascript and your "typo" makes it invalid.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko No, it does not. I'd like to learn something new (creating more complex matchings like the one I described). If I wanted to just make it work I would use eval as you suggested. – user1100671 5 mins ago

Comment: There is no such thing as "almost JSON". It is either conformant or not. If it is not conformant, then fix the source.

Comment: @torazaburo How can I make Steam fix their api? Please share your mighty power with me.

Comment: I don't know anything about steam. However, it would surprise me greatly if they are passing you something which claims to be JSON which is not. It would surprise me greatly if they are passing you something which claims to be valid JS object literal syntax but fails to escape a single quote. I suspect, without being at all sure, that there is something you could be missing about their API. If in fact they are sending you malformed JSON, then how are the other tens of thousands of people using that API dealing with it? Perhaps this is something you could take up on their support board.

Comment: @torazaburo well... I don't really care what surprises you. I repeat again: my question is how to match strings `/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g` that aren't in strings matchable by `/([\'](?:.)*[\'])/g`. There is nothing about "how to parse steam's JSON which sometimes happens to be javascript instead?". Please read the comments under the post you're answering before you write something. You can safely skip the information where my JSON comes from.

Comment: Yes, great solution, if you want to ignore the fact that you're probably trying to solve a problem which doesn't need to be solved, and that if you do manage to "solve" it with an unwieldy regexp, you will be fixing bugs in it for the rest of your life.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
['"]?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)['"]?:[\s\n]
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/mM3dP2/4

**edit:**

For css and Json keys

```
[{,;]\s*['"]?([-\w]+)['"]?:[\s\n]
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/mM3dP2/6

@SlashmanX

Comment: Note: This will cause issues with text with space after semi-colon, which may be present in some games "Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas" for example

Comment: This works for my sample json, but fails in css code ( `sample: 'blah blah background: red; blah blah'` )

Comment: would you match the word : "background"?

Comment: Why would I want to match: ` app_data: 
    { '12-3': ` ? This is not an answer for specified question.